# dropdown 2 Giving specific value from json based on dropdown1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have 2 dropdown lists and this is my json that should fill those drops:

```
$scope.categorias = [
    {nome:"Blusa", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50"]},
    {nome:"Camisa",  tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50"]},
    {nome:"Calça", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50","52","54","56","58","60"]},
    {nome:"Casaco", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50"]},
    {nome:"Sobretudo", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50"]},
    {nome:"Saia", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50","52","54","56","58","60"]},
    {nome:"Vestido", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50","52","54","56","58","60"]},
    {nome:"Blazer",tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50","52","54","56","58","60"]},
    {nome:"Gravata", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50","52","54","56","58","60"]},
    {nome:"Camisa", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50","52","54","56","58","60"]},
    {nome:"leggins", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50","52","54","56","58","60"]},
    {nome:"Cueca", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50"]},
    {nome:"Sutiâ", tamanhos:["55","60","65","70","75","80","85","90"]},
    {nome:"Pijama", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50","52","54","56","58","60"]},
    {nome:"Chapeu", tamanhos:["46","48","50","52","54"]},
    {nome:"Gorro", tamanhos:["46","48","50","52","54"]},
    {nome:"Sapato", tamanhos:["18","20","22","24","26","28","30","32","34","36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50","52"]},
    {nome:"Oculos", tamanhos:["54","55","56","57"]},
    {nome:"Bolsa", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50"]},
    {nome:"Cachecol", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50"]},
    {nome:"Cinto", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50"]}
]
```

**in the first one i want just the string related to the name, i did it like that:**

```
<select class="form-control" name="categorias" ng-model="produtos.categoria" ng-options="option.nome as option.nome for option in categorias | orderBy:'nome' " >
                    <option value="">- Selecciona uma categoria -</option>
</select>
```

in the second i want the tamanhos that is related to the name that i get in the frist drop,

for example: in the first drop i get Oculos so when i click in the drop1 i want drop 2 be filled with : "54","55","56","57"  i gave the example with the smallest :D

**so i did this:**

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Tamanho</label>
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="produtos.tamanho" ng-options=" produtos.categoria for option in categorias.tamanhos"></select>
            </div>
```

but doesn't work :S need some help to figure out :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right path, you just need to use the second field of category for second select binding, meaning instead of `option.nome as option.nome` you should use `option as option.nome`:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.categorias = [
    {nome:"Blusa", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50"]},
    {nome:"Camisa",  tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50"]},
    {nome:"Calça", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50","52","54","56","58","60"]},
    {nome:"Casaco", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50"]},
    {nome:"Sobretudo", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50"]},
    {nome:"Saia", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50","52","54","56","58","60"]},
    {nome:"Vestido", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50","52","54","56","58","60"]},
    {nome:"Blazer",tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50","52","54","56","58","60"]},
    {nome:"Gravata", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50","52","54","56","58","60"]},
    {nome:"Camisa", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50","52","54","56","58","60"]},
    {nome:"leggins", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50","52","54","56","58","60"]},
    {nome:"Cueca", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50"]},
    {nome:"Sutiâ", tamanhos:["55","60","65","70","75","80","85","90"]},
    {nome:"Pijama", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50","52","54","56","58","60"]},
    {nome:"Chapeu", tamanhos:["46","48","50","52","54"]},
    {nome:"Gorro", tamanhos:["46","48","50","52","54"]},
    {nome:"Sapato", tamanhos:["18","20","22","24","26","28","30","32","34","36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50","52"]},
    {nome:"Oculos", tamanhos:["54","55","56","57"]},
    {nome:"Bolsa", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50"]},
    {nome:"Cachecol", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50"]},
    {nome:"Cinto", tamanhos:["36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50"]}
];
  
  $scope.log = function (cat) {
    console.log(cat);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
      <select class="form-control" name="categorias" ng-change="log(produtos.categoria)" ng-model="produtos.categoria" ng-options="option as option.nome for option in categorias | orderBy:'nome' " >
                    <option value="">- Selecciona uma categoria -</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group">
                <label>Tamanho</label>
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="produtos.tamanho" ng-options="v for v in produtos.categoria.tamanhos">
<option value="">- Selecciona tamanho -</option>
</select>
            </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the full value of `categoria` to `produtos.categoria` and then use it in the second `select`.

```
<select
    name="categorias"
    ng-model="produtos.categoria"
    ng-options="categoria as categoria.nome for categoria in categorias"
>
    <option value="">- Selecciona uma categoria -</option>
</select>

<select
    ng-model="produtos.tamanho"
    ng-options="id in produtos.categoria.tamanhos"
></select>
```

P.S.: Please use English in your code, at least if you are asking for help here. Thanks :)